# SSH Daemon readiness problem

Tags: server, ssh

I have an old laptop running as a server (It runs Ubuntu Natty).

When I SSH into the box, it often takes a long time to log on, if it's been a while since last time I logged on. I suspect the reason to be that the SSH daemon is put to sleep somehow, and has to be woken before I can log on.
Can anyone explain why this happens?

### Additional info

Besides SSHD the server runs Transmission Daemon and two Dropbox instances.

I have appended "UseDNS no" to /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

The machine is running a desktop kernel, because I use it as a backup desktop machine as well. Would it help to change it to a server kernel, or would that disable my desktop?
I have read that there might be issues with nVidia drivers when running a server kernel, but don't know if this applies on Natty.

Comment: You have a desktop system running servers? If so... this could be attributed to hibernate/suspend. At least that would be my 1st idea.

Comment: No, it doesn't suspend. There's no wake-on LAN, and Transmission is seeding constantly.

Comment: if transmission is seeding it may just be a congested network problem.

Comment: Well, it might. However, I have a limit on so it only uses ~60% bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the "-v" parameter to the "ssh" client will give you visible output as to what is going on in the SSH handshake. This will help you identify where it is stalling. One common option to disable on the server is the following in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Comment: I know about the -v (and -vvv) option, but didn't know about that option. Will test thoroughly.

Comment: It seems to be always slow at "debug1: Entering interactive session.". I will try the option.

Comment: Seems like I didn't post my other comment. The option is already commented out. Other than that, it seems to be very connecting that is the issue, so the daemon could be sleeping.