# SSH very slowly connect

Tags: ssh

When I do `ssh root@ip_adress` I receive password request through 7-8 seconds waiting. It happens when I do it with keys too.

This is not server side problem I'm sure(Centos or Debian connecting to the same server instantly). That's what I took to solve the problem:

Deleted  «session optional pam_motd.so» from /etc/pam.d/login and /etc/pam.d/sshd 
UseDNS no in /etc/pam.d/sshd 
And it's not working

*sorry for my English

When I started `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -d -d` then `ssh -v host` I got this:

```
debug1: No valid Key exchange context   debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic 
**WAIT 3-4 Sec**
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more       information No Kerberos credentials available
**WAIT 2-3 Sec**      
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more       information No Kerberos credentials available W debug1: Unspecified  GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information 
**WAIT 2-3 Sec**   
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more       information No Kerberos credentials available 
**WAIT 2-3 Sec**     
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey 
debug1: Offering RSA       public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa debug1: Authentications that can       continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password 
debug1:       Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa debug1: Trying private key:       /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Comment: The debug output is all on one line so I can't even edit it easily to fix it - are you able to re-post that and use the "code" button to format it as code?

Comment: Sorry. It's fixed

Comment: What's telling you `tail -f /var/log/auth.log` on the server?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer. Not as an edit to the original post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSH Daemon readiness problem](http://askubuntu.com/q/58092/65926)

Answer (score 7):

Problem solved by adding `GSSAPIAuthentication no` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: To clarify, setting `GSSAPIAuthentication no` on the *host* Ubuntu system solves this.